# MySQL Select rows where the user has not voted yet (contest app)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a photo contest app where users can vote. I would like to select all of the contests where the logged in user has not voted yet.

**So I have two tables.**

The "contest" table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `contest` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `desc` text NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `started_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `nb_user_min` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nb_photo_max` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nb_photo_per_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The "contest_vote" table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `contest_vote` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pic_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contest_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

So to be clear, I want to get the number (or the list) of contests where the user has not voted yet. So I have tried with a `LEFT JOIN` but it doesn't return the good set of result. Here it the query I have until now :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.title, cv.user_id
FROM contest c
LEFT JOIN contest_vote cv
ON cv.contest_id = c.id AND cv.user_id != ?
GROUP BY contest_id
```

("?" represents the user_id parameter).

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple do with a subquery. Just grab all contest without where user is voted like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.title
FROM contest c
WHERE c.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT cv.contest_id FROM contest_vote cv WHERE cv.user_id = ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.title, cv.user_id
FROM contest c
LEFT JOIN contest_vote cv ON cv.contest_id = c.id AND cv.user_id != ? WHERE c.user_id = ?
GROUP BY contest_id
```